# Is it possible to query the output of a BigQuery stored procedure (maybe as a view?) using Metabase BI?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, view, google-bigquery, metabase

Is it possible to use Metabase to query the output of a BigQuery stored procedure?

I have a complex hierarchical relationship query that I am trying to port from postgres -> BigQuery that uses `WITH RECURSIVE` on PG which does not exist on BigQuery. From some research it seems possible to represent that using an iterative approach in a stored procedure.

However, I was hoping to be able to query the output of that query as a 'view' from Metabase (a business intelligence tool) and other applications, running further aggregations and filters on top of the flattened data.

However, I cannot find a way to `CALL` the stored procedure within a view or materialized view definition and so I think I am out of luck - but am hoping that there is  a way I haven't found!

The only alternative I can think of, is to run the stored procedure on a schedule and materialize it by hand to a table - but that seems:

1. Overly complex and manually managed and
2. Inefficient, as although the data is expected to be 'fresh' (valid on a minute by minute basis) it may not be queried at all times of the day - so pre-emptively materializing say once a minute will be wasteful.

Cheers.